# Exporting Hive to CSV with data type integrity

Tags: r, csv, hive, export

The table that is present in Hive is in the following format:

```
desc table_name;
col_id                double
col_ts                string
col_nm                string
cols_nm               string
col_cd                string
col_state_cd          string
```

I am using the following code to export it to a csv :

```
 hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from table_name' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /home/yourfile.csv
```

But when I read it through R, the data type of *col_id* changes to strings.
How to I ensure that data format is same as in Hive?

Comment: How are you reading it into R? You can always coerce with `Data$col_id = as.numeric(Data$col_id)`, but there is probably some sort of character forcing R to read the column in as string type.

Comment: I am reading it using  demo_tables<- read.csv("my_table.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE) but the *my_table.csv* is dynamic in nature. It might hold some other table where there might be some other columns with other names. So I need to ensure the data type is same while transferring it to CSV from Hive.

Comment: Also, if I open the csv using excel, it shows all columns as string. So it is happening while export from HIve to CSV and not while reading it into R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Hadley Wickham's [readr package](https://github.com/hadley/readr) -- it's  great at guessing at data types.

```
require(readr)
demo_tables <- read_csv("my_table.csv")
```